# Populating controlled inputs in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently building a form with React, and I'm wondering what the best practices are for pre-filling fields from an object.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class EditResourceForm extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      resource: props.resource
    }
  }

  handleFieldChanged (e) {
    // update state
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.resource.email}
        onChange={::this.handleFieldChanged} />
    )
  }
}
```

I'm encountering a problem when `this.state.resource.email` is null or undefined, because React does not want me providing those as values to controlled components:

```
Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using the   
empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled    
components.
```

Where is the proper place to provide an empty string as a fallback for a `null` value? Should this be done in the parent component's constructor method? Is there a way to avoid having to do this explicitly for every attribute that might have a `null` value?

Comment: Do it exactly as you're doing it now, just set `resource: props.resource` to `resource: props.resource || {}` so it doesn't throw an error if *props.resource* is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      resource: props.resource || {}
    }
  }
```

As far as I know there is no way to automatically set this values so they are not null, but if there was, I would not recommend it, good code is self explanatory.

**EDIT 1**

If this is still not enough, then the other option is using [uncontrolled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), however, straight from the documentation of react:

> Since an uncontrolled component keeps the source of truth in the DOM,
>   it is sometimes easier to integrate React and non-React code when
>   using uncontrolled components. It can also be slightly less code if
>   you want to be quick and dirty. Otherwise, you should usually use
>   controlled components.

**EDIT 2**

The code provided on the documentation seems a little convoluted, so here is a snippet of how I would do it:

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e, val) => {this.setState({email: val})}} />
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing (however, setting the individual attributes of the resource object to empty strings if `null`). Becomes quite tedious with longer forms, because I have many values that must be explicitly provided.

Comment: If it is really tedious for you can use uncontrolled components, and update the state only on value change (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), but beware, read the page and you will realize it might not always be the best idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `defaultValue` prop to set an initial value.

```
<input
  type="text"
  defaultValue={this.state.resource.email ? this.state.resource.email : ""}
  onChange={this.handleFieldChanged} />
```

Check out this great documentation about controlled vs uncontrolled components: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: I believe `defaultValue` is only available to uncontrolled inputs, and my form requires controlled components.